# Why my TopAppBar not getting displayed in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to change the background color of TopAppBar but my TopAppBar doesn't get displayed. I have added the code below. I have added the required Modifier so it can show the background color as Magenta but it doesn't show any color. I am not even sure it's displaying the TopAppBar

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.movieapp.ui.theme.MovieAppTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
             MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    MovieAppTheme {
       Scaffold(topBar = {
                   MyTopAppBar()
       }) {

       }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar() {
    TopAppBar(title = {Text(text = "Hello")},
        Modifier.background(color = Color.Red)
    )
}
```

Comment: You can't use the modifier you have to use the parameter colors

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the TopAppBarColors

```
TopAppBar(title = {Text(text = "Hello")}, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(containerColor = Color.Red))
```

BTW regarding the "I'm not sure it's even displaying it" there's an easy solution: the layout inspector :)

Comment: Anyone else think it crazy that you need to set the `colors` attribute before you can see your `TopAppBar`?